# Zend DB - Count(*) not working

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-table, mysql-error-1054

My sql statement is not working with Zend, its complaining about the Count(*) field... what am I doing wrong?

```
// get open/closed
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT status, count(*) as total FROM reported_issues WHERE date_reported >= '.$today.' AND status IN (0,1) GROUP BY status');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    switch ($row['status'])
    {
        case 0:
            $totalIssuesToday = $row['total'];
            break;

        case 1:
            $totalIssuesClosedToday = $row['total'];
            break;
    }
}
```

and the errors...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message
'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Y' in 'where clause''
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dating\trunk\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:238

Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dating\trunk\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(283): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dating\trunk\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(484): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\dating\trunk\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(235): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT status, ...', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\dating\trunk\html\siteadmin.php(59): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT status, ...')
#4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dating\trunk\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 238
```

Comment: "its complaining" - Got some detail on the error? Are you getting a Zend_Db_Exception or what?

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated it, my bad.

Comment: what is in $today ? Should that be quoted?

Comment: What does your $today variable look like?  Can you put all of the sql in a variable and output it so we can see how it evaluates in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complaint is actually about the `WHERE` -- looks like your `$today` variable does not contain what you think it should. Specifically, since it says:

```
'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Y' in 'where clause''
```

it seems your variable contains a `Y` that shouldn't be there.  The `count` appears to have nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: nailed it... forgot the DATE(' ... ') around my mask... DOH

Answer (score 6):

Aside from what others have noted about the value you have in $today, you really should be using bound parameters with your queries

```
<?php

$stmt = $db->query(
    "SELECT status, count(*) as total
       FROM reported_issues
      WHERE date_reported >= ?
        AND status IN (0,1)
      GROUP BY status"
    ,array( $today )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing your $today variable is corrupt. Change the first line (for testing)

from

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT status, count(*) as total FROM reported_issues WHERE date_reported >= '.$today.' AND status IN (0,1) GROUP BY status');
```

to:

```
$sql='SELECT status, count(*) as total FROM reported_issues WHERE date_reported >= '.$today.' AND status IN (0,1) GROUP BY status';
try{
   $stmt = $db->query($sql);
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $sql."\n";
   throw $e;
}
```

Then you can see the raw SQL it's trying to execute.